# How can I load another HTML page when SVG animation is finished?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, load

I have a HTML page (`animation.html`) with a SVG animation inside of it. The animation runs ca. 5 seconds and I would like to load another HTML page (`website.html`) when the SVG animation is finished.

I tried using jQuery's `load`-function but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('div').load('page')` like this?

Comment: Have you tried `onend` on the svg element? It would help if you create a jsfiddle from the code of your animation.html site. So people can see it directly and update it to show you a possible solution.

Comment: This is my animation on the first HTML page : [Animation SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/Nalepa/fxtes342/)

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can add an end transition handler to the last path transition in your SVG. So you do not depend on setTimeout and you can be sure that your animation has actually ended - in case you'll change the duration for example)

See the [created jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvydz1s3/2/)

the code inserted in your fiddle:

```
if(a === this.paths.length - 1) {
    b.addEventListener(e, function (event) {
        alert("end last transition");
        document.location.href = 'https://www.google.fr/';
    });
}
```

There's a check in the loop if it's the last path (line: 153 in the fiddle)
it than calls an alert and redirects to google.fr. (The redirect doesn't work from fiddle because google doesn't allow cross-origin).

There might be a better solution but the code is actually kinda hard to debug. All objects, variables etc. are called a,b,c etc. what makes it a bit difficult to update...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript

```
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.url.com';",300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this: `setTimeout("location.href = 'www.url.com';",5000);` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to first wait till the SVG is loaded and then put the timer to move the user to other page.
Try this:

```
$('#your_svg_id').load('sample.svg', function(data){
    //svg loaded.
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location='http://redirecthere.com';
    }, 5000); //5seconds
});
```

Comment: It works fine for `SetTimeout` function. But "sample.svg", i replace it with what ? My svg is include in HTMl file, not in an separate svg file.